# How to monitor a nodejs (non web) application by newrelic?

Tags: node.js, newrelic

I am trying to use nodejs with KCL to get records from kinesis. And now I want to monitor the situation of my application with newrelic.

I followed steps in https://github.com/newrelic/node-newrelic . But now no info was posted to newrelic.

Comment: Contact NewRelic support..

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking the New Relic agents will not post anything to newrelic.com unless there's a certain amount of activities. So if no functions are called, etc, on the node.js code, I would assume the New Relic agent would take a lazy approach and not send anything.